# working with a list across methods in c# using winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I am working on a problem where I load a text file into a string list and display in a listbox (which I have done) but I now want a button event to place the contents of the list in a second listbox which is just coming up blank. I can easily do this in VB but I'm fairly new to C# and realise I am probably missing something obvious.

```
namespace texttoarray
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public int counter;
        public List<string> finalList;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<string> finalList = AddToList();

        }

        public List<string> AddToList()
        {
            counter = 0;
            string line;
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"list.txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(line);
                list.Add(line);
                counter++;
            }


            //listBox2.DataSource = list;

            MessageBox.Show(counter.ToString());
            return list;
        }


        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox2.DataSource = finalList;

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Did you try to `ListBox.Refresh()` it?

Comment: Can you post how you do it in VB.NET?

Comment: I've posted an answer. See if it works for you now.

Comment: Thomas Weller, In VB.net, I would just declare an array in the form class which can easily be used across all methods - DIM myArray() as String, then use a for next loop to populate it.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a local list in constructor. You should assign result of `AddToList` method to field `finalList`.

**Your code:**

```
 List<string> finalList;
 public Form1()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    List<string> finalList = AddToList();         //Creation of new local variable 'finalList'
 }
```

**Solution:**

```
List<string> _finalList;            
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _finalList = AddToList();            //Use '_finalList' field
}
```

**Note:** You could have easily detected this if you have used appropriate naming conventions. i.e. Private field names should start with underscore. Public instance variables should start with Capital letter.